# Clean reinstall Ubuntu while recovering former account

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery, home-directory, user-profile

While tinkering (too much) with my machine, I deleted some apparently key files from the Ubuntu kernel on v22.*. I then thought I could "clean" reinstall just the system from a USB (that contained Ubuntu 20.*) but I believe I just created a new partition and basically left all my user data and software in a separate partition in `/media`.

[image]

The first partition that's mounted ("tguillerme-LabTop" - 276GB) contains my current `/home` and the Ubuntu distribution. The second one is in `/media` and contains my former `/home` and the broken Ubuntu distribution.

Is there a clean way to:

- remove the partition with the current version of Ubuntu installed (the 267GB one in the picture)
- clean reinstall Ubuntu from my USB on the former partition (the 665GB one)

I looked around for solutions ([like this trick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575783/recover-my-user-account-after-reinstalling-ubuntu)) but non of them seem to solve the two points above.

Comment: I like to keep system or / (root) separate from data, both for Windows & Linux. Most can just use separate partition for /home or use a large data partition and only have the mostly hidden in .dot files as user settings in / (root). Then separately backup /home and data files. You can do a "dirty" install where you do not format existing /. Just do not check the format box on /.  Must use Something Else install option. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941872

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how to set the mount point as / (or anything) in the "Something Else" option, everything seems to be blurred out and I can just remove partitions (or change format manually).

Comment: You need to know which partition was / and then click on it or change button. in manual partitioning. Then it should open screen to use as (/ ) and format (which you do not want to check). https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Please be clear/precise with details; 18.10 thru 20.04 were a two year development cycle; just as 20.10 thru 22.04 was the subsequent cycle; ie. two year development cycle ends with the LTS & starts just after release of the prior LTS, so 20.* makes no sense (given 20.04 & 20.10 are from different cycles; 20.10 being the first on road towards 22.04).  I stopped reading at version confusion.  You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop products (esp. *flavors*) without loss of user data, user configs etc. but problems in user configs will remain, global configs in systems directories will be new.